# DataFormatString not applied on property with a validation error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a view model with the following property:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "yyyy-MM-dd", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? ExpirationDate { get; set; }
```

The `DataFormatString` is such that when the value is populated in a `type="date"` input the browser will recognize it and prepopulate the date picker. In the controller, validations are run (using [FluentValidation](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation)) and added to the `ModelState`. If the `ModelState` is invalid, the view is re-rendered with the model. If the `ExpirationDate` has any errors on it though, then the `DataFormatString` appears to not be applied and the html ends up like:

```
<input class="input-validation-error error-highlight" id="ExpirationDate" name="ExpirationDate" type="date" value="11/2/2015 12:00:00 AM">
```

Which renders as if the field has no value. Note that if there are errors on *other* properties, the `ExpirationDate` still gets formatted correctly.

How can I ensure the date is formatted correctly even if it is invalid so the user can easily fix the error?